# Undefined method contacts_path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When attempting to go to my Contact us page(/contact/new) I am getting the error "NoMethodError in Contact#new undefined method 'contacts_path".  Is the issue with my routes?

**Routes for Contact:**

```
        contacts GET    /contacts(.:format)                   contacts#index
                       POST   /contacts(.:format)                   contacts#create
           new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)               contacts#new
          edit_contact GET    /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)          contacts#edit
               contact GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)               contacts#show
                       PATCH  /contacts/:id(.:format)               contacts#update
                       PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)               contacts#update
                       DELETE /contacts/:id(.:format)               contacts#destroy
```

**Contact Page Controller:**

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

 def new
 @contact = Contact.new
 end

 def create
 @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
 @contact.name =  contact.name
 @contact.email = contact.email
 @contact.message = contact.message
 @contact.company = contact.company

  if @contact.save
  flash[:notice] = "Your messsage has been sent"
  redirect_to '/'
   else
    flash[:error] = "Your message has not been sent please try again"
    render :new
  end
 end

 def contact_params
 params.require(:name, :email, :message).permit(:company)
 end
end
```

**View for Contact page - new.html.erb:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->  
 <head>
<!-- Meta -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">    
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">  
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic,300italic,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- Global CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
<!-- Plugins CSS -->    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/flexslider/flexslider.css">
<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link id="theme-style" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">

</head> 



    <div class="headline-bg contact-headline-bg">
    </div><!--//headline-bg-->


    <!-- ******Contact Section****** --> 
    <section class="contact-section section section-on-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="title text-center">Contact Us</h2>
            <p class="intro text-center">We’d love to hear from you!   </p>
            <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" method="post" action="">                    
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="contact-form-inner col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 xs-offset-0">
                        <div class="row">      
                            <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>                         
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">


                                <%= f.label :name, class: 'sr-only' %>
                                <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Your name" %>
                            </div>                    
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                <%= f.label :email, class: 'sr-only' %>
                                <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Your email address" %>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                <%= f.label :Company, class: 'sr-only' %>
                                <%= f.text_field :company, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Your company's name" %>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                <%= f.label :Message, class: 'sr-only' %>
                                <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 12, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter your message" %>

                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                <%= f.submit "Send Message", class: 'btn btn-block btn-cta btn-cta-primary' %>
                            </div>
                         <% end %>                           
                        </div><!--//row-->
                    </div>
                </div><!--//row-->
                <div id="form-messages"></div>
            </form><!--//contact-form-->
        </div><!--//container-->
    </section><!--//contact-section-->

    <!-- ******Other Contact Section****** --> 
    <section class="contact-other-section section">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h2 class="title">Other ways to reach us</h2>
            <p class="intro">You can also get in touch lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Donec ut massa consequat, bibendum metus pellentesque, pellentesque arcu. </p>
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="other-info list-unstyled col-md-6 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-1 xs-offset-0" >
                    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><a href="#">hello@yourwebsite.com</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><a href="https://twitter.com/Herewego" target="_blank">@SanSimon</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="tel:+0800123456">0800 123 456</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Queen Square <br /> 56 College Green Road<br />BS1 XR18<br />Bristol<br />UK</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--//row-->
        </div><!--//container-->
    </section><!--//contact-other-section-->




<!-- ******FOOTER****** --> 
<div id="footer-bottom">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <p>© Copyright 2016 <a href="#">The Group</a>. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>          
    </div>
</footer>




<script>
    /* ======= Fixed header when scrolled ======= */    
$(window).on('scroll load', function() {

     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
         $('#header').addClass('scrolled');
     }
     else {
         $('#header').removeClass('scrolled');

     }
});
</script>
```

Comment: what you do in create method?

Comment: man your controller name is singular make it plural

Comment: ah crapt!  Thanks uzaif.  That's why its looking for the plural contacts_path.  Just change the name in the controller file to ContactsController < ApplicationController?

Comment: can i post as answer?

Comment: Ok, hopefully that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the singular naming for your controller.

You could run

`rails d controller contact`

to delete the contact Contact controller.

Then you could run

`rails g controller contracts`

to generate the new **Contracts** controller. Copy and paste what you had in the `ContactController` and also check that your routes are updates as well.

Comment: Cool, let me know how it goes.

Comment: I deleted that controller and generated another one and copied the logic from the original into ContactsController.  And now I'm getting the error "undefined method 'contacts_path'."

Comment: did you redefine the `routes`? You would need to put in something like `resources :contacts` in `routes.rb`

Comment: Yes here I have them here:

bundle exec rake routes | grep -i contact
(in /Users/user/code/main)
              contacts_new POST /contacts/new(.:format)               contacts#new
                           GET  /contacts/new(.:format)               contacts#new

Comment: What do you have defined in your `routes.rb` for contacts?

Comment: @TakehiroMouri means what routes you define for contact ?

Comment: Yes, can you go into your `routes.rb` file and post it please?

Comment: These are the routes I have defined for contact the same as posted before the last one:

post 'contacts/new'

  get 'contacts/new'

Comment: Then you need to define the path for the index method. Alternatively, just add `resources: contacts` to your `routes.rb` and delete `post 'contacts/new' get 'contacts/new'`.

Comment: I don't need an index path.  I just need just really a POST for 'contacts/new'.   That still doesn't work for me.  When the user clicks on Contact us it is supposed to automatically render the new.html.erb page for contacts.

Comment: Okay when I added new_contact_path for URL it was able to get past the error.  Now I'm getting a undefined method 'body' error.  I'll go ahead and mark this one as the answer.

Comment: I think what you want is a POST for contacts/create. contacts/new should be a GET if you follow REST conventions ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have ambiguous routes, controller and views.
`@contact` in your form will generate the `contacts_path` as default

You can do this by following these steps:
Change the `routes.rb` file

**routes.rb**

```
resources :contacts
```

Change your controller into plural name

```
rails generate controller contacts
```

Then, restart your server.

I hope this helps you.